# My dropdown of nav bar is not working properly

Tags: html, css

```
My dropdown of the navigation bar is not working properly

I have tried to lookout on many forums. But none of them solved my problem.
```

My navigation bar is not functioning properly, I have made it out of CSS and HTML.

1) the dropdown arrow is not displaying for partner and services button.

2)After hovering or clicking a drop down should appear and, it is not appearing on my screen.

These are the issues I am facing. So can you guys help me and guide resolve my issues.

```css
nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 78%;
  background-color: #757575;
}

.navbar navbar-default {
  background-color: #757575;
}

a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #757575;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}


/* The navigation menu */

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Navigation links */

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* The subnavigation menu */

.subnav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Subnav button */

.subnav .subnavbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Add a red background color to navigation links on hover */

.navbar a:hover,
.subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: red;
}


/* Style the subnav content - positioned absolute */

.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Style the subnav links */

.subnav-content a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Add a grey background color on hover */

.subnav-content a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}


/* When you move the mouse over the subnav container, open the subnav content */

.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  display: block;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 130px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}


/* When the input field gets focus, change its width to 100% */

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">About <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#company">Company</a>
      <a href="#team">Team</a>
      <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">Services <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
      <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
      <a href="#package">Package</a>
      <a href="#express">Express</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">Partners <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>

</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and tell us the thing that doesn't work? I made a snippet out of your code and I observe that something does work, but we cannot know what were your intentions.

Comment: yes be precise for the person who is reading your question so that he can answer your problem

Comment: I have updated my question. Please revisit

Comment: I think you forgot the font-awesome CSS & font file

Comment: after adding the script, the buttons have appeared.But the dropdown menu is not showing stil

Answer (score 0):

Add `font` `CSS` file

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

```css
nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 78%;
  background-color: #757575;
}

.navbar navbar-default {
  background-color: #757575;
}

a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #757575;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}


/* The navigation menu */

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Navigation links */

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* The subnavigation menu */

.subnav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Subnav button */

.subnav .subnavbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Add a red background color to navigation links on hover */

.navbar a:hover,
.subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: red;
}


/* Style the subnav content - positioned absolute */

.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Style the subnav links */

.subnav-content a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Add a grey background color on hover */

.subnav-content a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}


/* When you move the mouse over the subnav container, open the subnav content */

.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  display: block;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 130px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}


/* When the input field gets focus, change its width to 100% */

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">About <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#company">Company</a>
      <a href="#team">Team</a>
      <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">Services <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
      <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
      <a href="#package">Package</a>
      <a href="#express">Express</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">Partners <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>

</div>
```

Comment: added the script, but still, the dropdown  is not appearing when I am clicking the buttons

Answer (score 0):

It's working perfectly fine. Check the below snippet. You need to add `font-awesome` CDN

```css
nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 78%;
  background-color: #757575;
}

.navbar navbar-default {
  background-color: #757575;
}

a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #757575;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}


/* The navigation menu */

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Navigation links */

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* The subnavigation menu */

.subnav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Subnav button */

.subnav .subnavbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Add a red background color to navigation links on hover */

.navbar a:hover,
.subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: red;
}


/* Style the subnav content - positioned absolute */

.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Style the subnav links */

.subnav-content a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Add a grey background color on hover */

.subnav-content a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}


/* When you move the mouse over the subnav container, open the subnav content */

.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  display: block;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 130px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}


/* When the input field gets focus, change its width to 100% */

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">About <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#company">Company</a>
      <a href="#team">Team</a>
      <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">Services <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
      <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
      <a href="#package">Package</a>
      <a href="#express">Express</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">Partners <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>

</div>
```

Comment: where do i add the CDN

Comment: Add it in between`<head></head>`

Comment: tried it still not working maybe i will give the rest of my html file here to

Comment: The code which you have posted was working. Maybe you have intalled some adblocker extensions. Try incognito mode